# Spring Boot - profile activating other Profile

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm working on a spring boot application and would like to have something like a basic profile inheritance.

I wonder how can I archive the following:

```
if profile A.hello is active
then profile A.world needs to be activated as well
```

is there a way to do this?

Answer (score -1):

You can get the active profiles by autowiring the Environment variable

```
@Autowired
Environment environment;
...
environment.getActiveProfiles()
```

Comment: it's not about autowring them in. It's about activating other once, based on existing profiles.